# purrr::map_if How to return value if condition is FALSE?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am running a function using `purrr::map` that will return an error if the dataframe does not contain numeric data (i.e., na.omit do not return any valid rows). I discovered map_if but it seems map_if returns .x if .p is false. Is there a way to return NA. This example should explain what I need:

```
library(openair)
library(tidyverse)

# Build test dataset
df1 <- mydata
df2 <- mydata
df2$no2 <- NA_real_
df3 <- mydata
dfx <- tibble(id = c(1, 2, 3), data = list(df1, df2, df3))

# polarPlot function will return error if dataframe does not contain numeric data (i.e., it only contains NAs)
polarPlot(df2, pollutant = "no2")

# Function to test length of dataframe (i.e., if 0 theneverything is NAs)
check_length <- function(x) (x %>% select(ws, wd, "no2") %>% na.omit() %>% nrow()) > 0
check_length(df1)
check_length(df2)

# purrr::map (is there a way for map_if to return NA if length == 0?) 
dfx %>% mutate(mynewvar = map_if(.x = data, check_length, ~ polarPlot(.x, pollutant = "no2")))
```

In other words, I would like `mynewvar[[2]]` to return NA.

Comment: You can try using `possibly()` to make your function handle errors safely and then use `compact()` to handle all the NAs. Unsure if that will work since you didn't post a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

@dylanjm I posted a reprex not sure if you are not able to see it. As you suggested the function `possibly` is what I need.

```
possible_polarPlot <- possibly(polarPlot, otherwise = NA)
out <- dfx %>% mutate(mynewvar = map(.x = data, ~ possible_polarPlot(.x, pollutant = "no2")))
out$mynewvar[[2]] # Returns NA as I was looking for.
```

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize `mydata` was an actual df object of `library(openair)`. Glad it works.